# Regex to match single letter from A to Z

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex to match a single letter in a string (from A to Z in order):

It should find the letter 'A', if there are no 'A's, it should find the letter 'B', then 'C', and so on...

**Examples** ->

- BCD**A**E
- C**B**DE  -> Since there's no 'A's, it matches with `B`
- Y**X**Z
- B**A**AC -> Since there're two 'A's, it finds the leftmost
  character first.

---

**Extra Information:**

I'd provide an example, as some users don't seem to like questions without code.

> Given a lower case string remove k characters from that string. First
>   remove all letter 'a', followed by letter 'b', then 'c', etc..

.This was my solution:

```
public static String remove(String s, int k) {
  for (int c : s.chars().sorted().limit(k).toArray())
    s = s.replaceFirst(Character.toString((char) c), "");
  return s;
}
```

But I'd like to try this with a regex like:

```
public static String remove(String s, int k) {
  while (k-- > 0)
    s = s.replaceFirst(MY_MAGIC_REGEX_STR, "");
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you loop over a set of characters and stop at first occurrence?

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. But this is for learning purposes. I want it to do with regex.

Comment: Try a similar pattern like `^(?:[^A]*(A)|[^B]*(B)|[^C]*(C)|...)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/AwCHEx/1

Comment: @revo Isn't that match with more than one character?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @revo it should find only a single char. If there is `A`s, find the leftmost A. If there is no 'A's but have B, match with the leftmost B.

Comment: You have capturing groups and you can use back-references. Using `\K` in PCRE this would be equivalent to `^(?:.*?\KA|.*?\KB|.*?\KC|...)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/27XlR4/1

Comment: @revo that is cool. Would you be able to provide an answer with Java's equivalent to it?

Answer (score 3):

Regex might not be the best tool suited for this problem.  I think the easiest thing to do here is to just convert your input string to an array of characters, and then walk down that array, keeping track of what the minimum (smallest) character is:

```
public char findLowestChar(String input) {
    char[] array = input.toCharArray();
    char chr = 'Z';     // works so long as input is non-empty
    for (int i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (array[i] < chr) {
            chr = array[i];
        }
    }
    return chr;
}
```

I am assuming here that the input string would always have at least one letter A-Z in it.  If not, and you also wanted to implement this inside a method, then you should also handle the empty input case.

**Edit:**

You just substantially changed your question.  But it turns out the above code can still be part of the updated answer.  You can now iterate `k` times, and at each step run the above code to find the lowest letter.  Then, do a `String#replaceAll` to remove all occurrences of that letter.

```
String input = "BCDAE";
// remove k=4 characters, starting with (maybe) A, from the input string
for (int k=0; k < 4 && input.length() > 0; ++k) {
    char lowest = findLowestChar(input);
    input = input.replaceAll(String.valueOf(lowest), "");
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. But the questions did ask for a regex string.

Comment: That's fine.  I don't think regex is the best tool for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex works as desired:

```
(?i)A|B(?!.*[A-A])|C(?!.*[A-B])|D(?!.*[A-C])|E(?!.*[A-D])|F(?!.*[A-E])|G(?!.*[A-F])|H(?!.*[A-G])|I(?!.*[A-H])|J(?!.*[A-I])|K(?!.*[A-J])|L(?!.*[A-K])|M(?!.*[A-L])|N(?!.*[A-M])|O(?!.*[A-N])|P(?!.*[A-O])|Q(?!.*[A-P])|R(?!.*[A-Q])|S(?!.*[A-R])|T(?!.*[A-S])|U(?!.*[A-T])|V(?!.*[A-U])|W(?!.*[A-V])|X(?!.*[A-W])|Y(?!.*[A-X])|Z(?!.*[A-Y])
```

The regex consists of 26 terms (one term per letter) which are concatenated via the alternation-operator (|). The A(?!B) is the negative look ahead operator which match A if A is not followed by B.The (?i) simply triggers case insensitivity.

On the whole the regex finds first all A's from left to right, than all B's from left to right and so on.

Because of the length of the regex it is more comfortable to generate it programmatically:

```
// Generate regEx
String regEx = "(?i)" + "A" + "|";  
for (char i = 'B'; i <= 'Z'; i++ ) {
    regEx += i + "(?!.*[A-" + (char)(i-1) + "])" + "|";
}
regEx = regEx.substring(0, regEx.length() - 1);
System.out.println(regEx);
```

For the following example:

```
String example = "AAAZZZHHAAAZZHHHAAZZZHH"; 

// Output
while(example.length() != 0) {
    System.out.println(example);
    example = example.replaceFirst(regEx, "");
}
```

the output is:

```
AAAZZZHHAAAZZHHHAAZZZHH
AAZZZHHAAAZZHHHAAZZZHH
AZZZHHAAAZZHHHAAZZZHH
ZZZHHAAAZZHHHAAZZZHH
ZZZHHAAZZHHHAAZZZHH
ZZZHHAZZHHHAAZZZHH
ZZZHHZZHHHAAZZZHH
ZZZHHZZHHHAZZZHH
ZZZHHZZHHHZZZHH
ZZZHZZHHHZZZHH
ZZZZZHHHZZZHH
ZZZZZHHZZZHH
ZZZZZHZZZHH
ZZZZZZZZHH
ZZZZZZZZH
ZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZ
ZZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZ
ZZ
Z
```